# zsh strange piping behavior (compared to bash)

Tags: bash, terminal, pipe, zsh

Say I have a file `test.sh` that executes some command (`ping` in this case) in the background:

```sh
for i in $(seq 1 30); do
  # This `ping` will "sleep" for 10s
  ping 10.0.0.0 -w 10 >/dev/null &
  jobs -r | wc -l
done
```

If I run `bash ./test.sh`, I got the expected output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
```

However, if I run `zsh ./test.sh`, the output is unexpected:

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

What is "wrong" here? How can I get the same output in `zsh` as that of `bash`?

```sh
$ zsh --version
zsh 5.8 (x86_64-debian-linux-gnu)
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.1.0(1)-rc3 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
jobs -r | wc -l
```

with

```
[[ "$ZSH_NAME" == "zsh" ]] && setopt MONITOR
jobs -r | wc -l
[[ "$ZSH_NAME" == "zsh" ]] && setopt NO_MONITOR
```

to enable and disable job control only with zsh.